# Error when loading csv data into Wave Analytics

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics, analytics-api

CSV file:

```
"id","name"
"00134535345343542X","Walmart"
"001342323423423232","Amazon"
```

Metadata JSON file:

```
{
    "fileFormat": {
    "charsetName": "UTF-8",
    "fieldsEnclosedBy": "\"",
    "fieldsDelimitedBy": ",",
    "numberOfLinesToIgnore": 1
  },
  "objects": [
  {
        "connector": "CIConnector",
        "description": "",
        "fullyQualifiedName": "CSVData",
        "label": "CSV Data",
        "name": "CSVData",
        "fields": [
        {
            "description": "",
            "fullyQualifiedName": "CSVData.Name",
            "label": "Acc Name",
            "name": "Name",
            "isSystemField": false,
            "isUniqueId": false,
            "isMultiValue": false,
            "type": "Text"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "fullyQualifiedName": "CSVData.Id",
            "label": "Acc Id",
            "name": "Id",
            "isSystemField": true,
            "isUniqueId": true,
            "type": "Text"
        }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When uploading the data using InsightsExternalData API, I am receiving the below error:

> Error executing node digest: field-count, 2, and header's
>   column-count, 1, do not match (02K34534523223231M_03C23423423243231A)

I created the CSV data and Metadata JSON following the documentation mentioned in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format/bi_ext_data_schema_overview.htm)

Clearly I have two fields in header and on every line, I have two fields.. Any help on this?

**NOTE:** I am receiving this error only when loading the data using Cast Iron and It loads fine if I load the above files in UI.

Comment: You have specified the name (and id) like this: CSVData.Name, CSVData.Id - yet in the csv file you have named them name and id. If the parser is case sensitive, this will cause an error (I'm not able to determine if this is the case)

Comment: Also, I notice that the example provided here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format/bi_ext_data_schema_overview.htm does not enclose the csv values in quotes, but you do. I think this is ok, but it's safest to stick to the example exactly

Comment: If I don't enclose data in quotes, how do I handle situations where account name has comma in it: ex: Wal,mart

Comment: Sure, I think it's fine. Try my first suggestion - it's all I can see at the moment.

Comment: Another thing you can do is leave out the metadata file altogether - if you are only using those two fields, it probably isn't needed - the docs say it's optional.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it did not work :( Regarding the metadata JSON file, I need this file because we will be uploading fields of type date and number. Without the metadata file, it assumes all fields as text type.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to try saving the file with various different text editors - sometimes the file format is not correct, sometimes the line endings are not right. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to posted on how I solved this. 
If you upload the above csv file and metadata from UI, it loads fine but it was failing for me when trying to load using Cast Iron.

Here is the documentation on Cast Iron website on how to load csv file into salesforce wave.

Link: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGR73_7.5.1/com.ibm.wci.doc/Salesforce_analytics_connector_LoadData_Activity.html

[image]

It says that the dataFile should be base64 encoded but it is not required.

The error in salesforce wave was kind of misleading and led me thinking that there was something wrong with the header but the fact is that it was trying to load the base64 encoded data.

Once I mapped the raw csv data to the field 'DataFile' on the object 'InsightsExternalDataPart' object, it loads fine.

I guess Cast Iron, internally encodes the file so we don't need to do explicitly.

Hope this helps future readers. Thanks!